# How to subscribe to Route changes in Navigator 2.0

Tags: flutter

I have my navigator setup and everything is working as expected, but I have a widget buried in my widget tree that needs to know about route changes and I can't figure out how to subscribe to them.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the name of the route, accessible anywhere:
ModalRoute.of(context).settings.name
and listen to the changes of that value.

But generally speaking, if you want to listen to some variable changes deep in the widget tree, you should look at some state management options.
Provider, Bloc or MobX are some options.
[flutter documentation on state management](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options)

Comment: Using `ModalRoute` didn't work for me. I ended up using a shared state for it.